# How to resolve the bug where the flashlight image/logo on the phone keep blinking even if the application and flashlight shut down?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using android studio falmingo 2022.2.1 patch 2
the project is in language kotlin
minimum sdk api 24: android 7.0 (Nougat)

tested on phone: galaxy s21 fe 5g

The application turns on the phone flashlight and make it blinking in some speed.
What I'm trying to do is when the user presses the back button that the application will be shut down.

for now the application does quit and shut down but the flashlight image on the phone keeps turning on/off for about 2-10 seconds before stopping.  the flashlight is turned off but the image of the flashlight is keep turning on/off.

here is short video I recorded my phone showing the problem:

at second 31 it's showing the blinking flashlight image on the phone while the application has shutdown and the flashlight is turned off. and in 1:11 I'm showing that I need to press the Force stop to really stop this blinking bug.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jE61tPUxzrg

link to my whole project in GitHub:

https://github.com/chocolade1972/Android-Blinking-Flashlight

this is my code in android studio:

```
package com.example.flashlight

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false
    var flashLightOn = false
    var counter: Long = 0
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)
        val seek = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    // Log.d("seekbar", "Your Progress: ${seekBar?.progress}"

                    counter = progress.toLong()
                    textView.text = counter.toString()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
            },
        )

        startFlashLight()

    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
        System.exit(0)
    }

    private fun openFlashLight() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (!flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    private fun closeFlashLight()
    {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    fun startFlashLight() {
        openFlashLight()
        flashLightOn = true

        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

        handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (flashLightOn) {
                    closeFlashLight()
                } else {
                    openFlashLight()
                }

                // Changing the toggle and calling the same Runnable again after 5 seconds
                flashLightOn = !flashLightOn
                handler.postDelayed(this, counter)
            }
        }, counter)
    }
}
```

tried to google and tried I think almost any answer in the onBackPressed
the current code in the function onBackPressed does close the application and the flashlight but also make the bug/s described above.

Comment: New account with the same name, or is this a bot?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I formatted my pc and forgot my login to my old account. I will delete this question and continue with the old one.